# Appium : Verify relative element presence

Tags: java, android, webdriver, appium

Can you give a suggestion(please see pic) how can I check if selectIndicator is present on one block then I should choose another one. I know how to check if that element isPresent on whole page, but I need to find if it present on particular element. In my example I have Living Room chosen, and I need to check if DVR not chosen -choose that one. Any idea how can I do it? I was trying to check this way, but no luck:

```
WebElement element= driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("First element").findElementByAccessibilityId("Second element");
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/F98DM.png]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use "if" operator for Appium tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004961/how-to-use-if-operator-for-appium-tests)

Comment: Not really duplicate. Your solution will check of element exist on the page,that can be done by using  isPresent or isDisplayed. But I need if element exist on specific locator(Xpath or id). Any idea how implement this?

Comment: you can try finding attributes of element and match with the expected ones like using WebElement w;
  w.getAttribute(arg0)
  w.getCssValue(arg0)
  w.getTagName()

Answer (score 0):

If I am not getting you wrong you want to implement a self defined data structure for an appropriate solution. That could be something similar to this :

```
public class DVRList {
//declare components required to comprise one item
private String dvrOptionText ;
private boolean dvrOptionCheck ;
// implement setter..getter for these two
}

...in some method set the value using the logic
DVRList dvrlist = new DVRList();
WebElement parentOfBoth = driver.findElement(By.xpath("
//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.R‌​elativeLayout[1]");
String text = parentOfBoth.findElementByAccessibilityId("First element").getText();
dvrlist.setdvrOptionText(text);
if(isElement(parenOfBoth.findElementByAccessibilityId("Second element"))
dvrlist.setdvrOptionCheck(true);
else dvrlist.setdvrOptionCheck(false);
```

and thereafter you can use these parameters accordingly.

**Note** : Parameters and approach are generalised and should be modified for serving the exact purpose.